# Why would one use "stop; exit 1" in an Upstart script rather than just "exit 1" in case of an error?

Tags: linux, shell, service, upstart, daemon

I am maintaining an Upstart script (version 0.6.5) and in the `pre-start script`, there's a test to terminate the service if a precondition is not met:

```
pre-start script
  if [ ! -f $REQUIRED_FILE ]; then
    echo "$REQUIRED_FILE does not exit" >> $LOG_FILE
    stop 
    exit 1
  fi
end script
```

According to the `csh`/`tcsh` reference documentation, `stop [jobIDs]`:

> *suspend[s] the current background jobs or the background jobs specified by jobIDs; this is the complement of Ctrl-Z or suspend.*

I don't see any use for `stop` here, especially in the `pre-start` section wherein the service has not started yet (i.e. by the `exec` stanza).

Am I missing something here? Or is `stop` here redundant and unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

Using `stop` inside of a job is equivalent to calling `sudo stop <job-name>`. This would be used if you wanted to disable the `respawn`-ing of a job.

The upstart documentation on the pre-start stanza has an example that explains this usage:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start

> Another possibility is to cancel the start of the job for some
>   reason. One good reason is that it's clear from the system
>   configuration that a service is not needed:
>
> ```
> pre-start script
>   if ! grep -q 'parent=foo' /etc/bar.conf ; then
>     stop ; exit 0
>   fi
> end script
> ```